Error inserting data: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Total_Price' in 'field list' when running my python script
Basically my python script takes data from  yfinance and then insert it into mysql database on phpmyadmin, I am mysql.connector for connecting to my database and inserting data.
Though I do not understand, I think database structure is correct and so is my list in the columns table, but still it leads to insertion problem, plus I have no expertise in sql so it dosent help my case much.
import yfinance as yf
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime

# Connect to MySQL database
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    port="3308",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="my_database"
)

# Define column names and their types
columns = [
    "Ticker VARCHAR(100)",
    "Total_Price INT(11)",
    "Bid INT(11)",
    "Ask INT(11)",
    "Open_Price INT(11)",
    "High INT(11)",
    "Low INT(11)",
    "Market_Volume INT(11)",
    "Name VARCHAR(100)",
    "Is_Active TINYINT(1)",
    "Last_Close_Price INT(11)",
    "Created_On DATETIME"
]


# Create a cursor object
cursor = db.cursor()

# Function to create table
def create_table():
    try:
        sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stock (StockID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,{})".format(", ".join(columns))
        cursor.execute(sql)
        print("Table created successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error creating table:", e)

# Function to insert data into database
def insert_data(stock_data):
    try:
        sql = "INSERT INTO stock ({}) VALUES ({})".format(", ".join(stock_data.keys()), ", ".join(["%s"] * len(stock_data)))
        cursor.execute(sql, list(stock_data.values()))
        db.commit()
        print("Data inserted successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error inserting data:", e)
        db.rollback()

# Function to fetch data from Yahoo Finance
def fetch_data(symbol):
    try:
        data = yf.Ticker(symbol)
        info = data.info
        stock_data = {
            "Ticker": symbol,
            "Total_Price": info.get("currentPrice"),
            "Bid": info.get("bid"),
            "Ask": info.get("ask"),
            "Open_Price": info.get("open"),
            "High": info.get("dayHigh"),
            "Low": info.get("dayLow"),
            "Market_Volume": info.get("volume"),
            "Name": info.get("longName"),
            "Is_Active": 1 if info.get("regularMarketTime") else 0,  # Checking if stock is active
            "Last_Close_Price": info.get("previousClose"),
            "Created_On": datetime.now()
        }
        return stock_data
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error fetching data for", symbol, ":", e)
        return None

# List of ticker symbols
tickers = [
    "RELIANCE.NS", "TCS.NS", "HDFCBANK.NS", "INFY.NS", "HINDUNILVR.NS"
]

# Create table
create_table()

# Fetch data for each ticker and insert into database
for ticker in tickers:
    stock_data = fetch_data(ticker)
    if stock_data:
        insert_data(stock_data)

# Close cursor and database connection
cursor.close()
db.close()

Gives the following error :-
Table created successfully
Error inserting data: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Total_Price' in 'field list'
Error inserting data: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Total_Price' in 'field list'
Error inserting data: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Total_Price' in 'field list'
Error inserting data: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Total_Price' in 'field list'
Error inserting data: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Total_Price' in 'field list'

Here is the image of my database and its structure


Print problematic value of sql variable and look at it.

@Akina If you mean this :- {'Ticker': 'HINDUNILVR.NS', 'Total_Price': 2323.3, 'Bid': None, 'Ask': None, 'Open_Price': 2349.55, 'High': 2355.8, 'Low': 2317.65, 'Market_Volume': 812060, 'Name': 'Hindustan Unilever Limited', 'Is_Active': 0, 'Last_Close_Price': 2349.6, 'Created_On': datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 15, 18, 25, 37, 883754)} then I tried it but all the values look right to me, and it converts those decimal values to int and put it in the database, done that before

printing 'table created sucessfuly' says only there is no error. I think it exists with different column names, without the underscore or something

@Turo I tried your method by removing underscores in both columns and stock_data and the I tried it removing underscore only on columns but keep it in stock_data and vice versa but it keep giving me the following error :-

@Turo Error :- Error creating table: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT(11), Bid INT(11), Ask INT(11), Open Price INT(11), High INT(11), Low INT(...' at line 1
Error inserting data: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Price, High, Low, Market_Volume, Name, Is_Active, Last_Close_Price, Created_O...' at line 1, I dont believe that removing underscore is rigt syntx

You replaced at least once the underscore with a blank, producing a syntax error, I meant deleting the underscore

If you mean this ?? This is NOT a value which is composed in the variable sql, after sql = "INSERT INTO ... and before cursor.execute(....
